# Qt Как закруглить углы на форме

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qt-designer

Пытался сделать с помощью QPainter, не получается, вот код:

```
 QPainter pain;
   this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);        
    pain.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    pain.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    pain.drawRoundedRect(rect(), 12, 12, Qt::AbsoluteSize);
```

С помощью QPainterPatch получилось, но края не знаю как сгладить, код:

```
  QPainterPath painPath;
 painPath.addRoundedRect(rect(), 8, 8, Qt::AbsoluteSize);
 this->setMask(painPath.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
```